# Silent Installation of FortiClient.msi VPN Only

Tags: powershell, silent-installer

I am trying to do a silent installation of FortiClient.msi, and here is what I have so far:

```
Start-Process "[Insert MSI Path]" /qn -Wait
```

I would like to make sure that the VPN is the only part that is installed. Is there a parameter that tells the msi to only install VPN, or will the installer automatically install VPN only?

Comment: It looks like there is some guidance here that might help: https://www.reddit.com/r/fortinet/comments/4k75nf/vpn_only_silent_installation_of_forticlient/

Answer (score 0):

You can open the msi file with [ORCA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and check the possible Properties. For example there is a property DISABLEFEATURE which could do your wanted stuff.